How to using setTimeout in side loop javascript for wait a second and then process next loop?
How to using setTimeout in side loop javascript for wait a second and then process next loop ?
i tried to using setTimeout in side for loop javascript for wait a second and then process next loop, but it's not work.
<script>
for (let i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
  setTimeout(function(){
      alert(i);
    }, 2000);
}
</script>

When run code i want to get result like this
wait 2 second then alert "1" wait 2 second then alert "2"

I think you're issue is answered here: JavaScript closures vs. anonymous functions. Please do [edit] the question and make it clear if you think it’s different, and make sure to say how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
